# Query Vars Not Set in Main Query

Tags: wp-query, query-variable

I have a function that checks page specific and global settings to determine a class related to sidebars. I call the function from the archive.php template and try to check that `post_type` is 'post', however the `post_type` var isn't set.

Relevant Code:

```
function get_sidebar_class() {
    global $wp_query;
    echo 'Post type: ' . get_query_var( 'post_type' );
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $wp_query->query_vars, true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

`post_type` comes back empty for both attempts. Why isn't it set? Other variables (E.g. `category`) are set, but not `post_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query vars are... fun like that. Depending on which archive you are messing with [`get_post_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type/) just might be simple enough to do it (it gets type from actual post, not query).

Otherwise you might want to go for [`get_queried_object()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object/) to figure out what precisely you are dealing with.

Comment: will get post type work on an archive page?

Comment: @GusRuss89 yes, but note that it will get type from the post (not query), which is _usually_ same for all posts in archive, but depends on your specifics.

Comment: Thanks, I think that should suffice for now. I don't intend to mix post types on the archives for now. A sidebar widget or something listing custom post types wouldn't mess with it would it?

Comment: @GusRuss89 it should be fine as long as secondary queries are properly reset.

Answer (score 1):

What type of page/post are you looking at when you echo this out? `post_type` does not get populated when looking at a `post` or `post archive`. Try on Pages and see if you see `post_type` at that point.

I believe `post_type` is populated on anything EXCEPT posts, and perhaps pages - Pages doesn't have an archive, so it may just have a `page` property storing an ID or slug, etc. Therefore, essentially it's only used for [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: @Eric_Holmes I'm just trying to make sure it's not a custom post type basically, so I guess I could check if `post_type` is empty AND `pagename` is empty (`page` isn't set on archive pages and `post_type` isn't set on pages), it just feels like it's not as solid a solution as it could be...

Answer (score 0):

Am alternate way of getting query vars is `$wp_query->get( 'post_type' ) ;`. If `post_type` is set, you can retrieve it that way.

Comment: Since `get_query_var()` wraps exactly this it won't help in this case.